# Holoview chart won't appear in Django site

Tags: django, bokeh, holoviews

i know there is probably something simple i am doing wrong, but i don't know where else to get an answer. I created a django site and the following function returns holoview html:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from charts.models import Ord

from IPython.display import display_html
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')

# Create your views here.

def displayChart(request):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(Ord.objects.using('DB').all().values('ordtyp')[:500]))
    df = df.groupby([df.ordtyp]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
    bars = hv.Bars(df, kdims=[('ordtyp', 'Order Type')], vdims=[('counts', 'Count of Orders')])
    hv.Store.registry['bokeh'][hv.Bars]
    html = renderer.html(bars)
    return render(request, 'charts/charts.html', {'html': html})
```

i put a block in the charts.html file as:

{{ html |safe }}

and all i get is a blank page. i then took the raw html that the renderer is returning and tried to copy and paste it directly into my html file, and got the same thing. the html is below. Also, the chart does work in Jupyter Notebook... can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

charts.html:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>     <title>Charts</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>     {{html|safe}}
> </body>
> </html>
```

raw html that the renderer returned:

```
<div style='display: table; margin: 0 auto;'>

    <div class="bk-root">
        <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="0dd69ef6-4d30-48f5-a95a-1201437920de"></div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  (function(root) {
    function now() {
      return new Date();
    }

    var force = false;

    if (typeof (root._bokeh_onload_callbacks) === "undefined" || force === true) {
      root._bokeh_onload_callbacks = [];
      root._bokeh_is_loading = undefined;
    }



    if (typeof (root._bokeh_timeout) === "undefined" || force === true) {
      root._bokeh_timeout = Date.now() + 0;
      root._bokeh_failed_load = false;
    }

    var NB_LOAD_WARNING = {'data': {'text/html':
       "<div style='background-color: #fdd'>\n"+
       "<p>\n"+
       "BokehJS does not appear to have successfully loaded. If loading BokehJS from CDN, this \n"+
       "may be due to a slow or bad network connection. Possible fixes:\n"+
       "</p>\n"+
       "<ul>\n"+
       "<li>re-rerun `output_notebook()` to attempt to load from CDN again, or</li>\n"+
       "<li>use INLINE resources instead, as so:</li>\n"+
       "</ul>\n"+
       "<code>\n"+
       "from bokeh.resources import INLINE\n"+
       "output_notebook(resources=INLINE)\n"+
       "</code>\n"+
       "</div>"}};

    function display_loaded() {
      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
        var el = document.getElementById("0dd69ef6-4d30-48f5-a95a-1201437920de");
        if (el != null) {
          el.textContent = "BokehJS " + Bokeh.version + " successfully loaded.";
        }
      } else if (Date.now() < root._bokeh_timeout) {
        setTimeout(display_loaded, 100)
      }
    }


    function run_callbacks() {
      try {
        root._bokeh_onload_callbacks.forEach(function(callback) { callback() });
      }
      finally {
        delete root._bokeh_onload_callbacks
      }
      console.info("Bokeh: all callbacks have finished");
    }

    function load_libs(js_urls, callback) {
      root._bokeh_onload_callbacks.push(callback);
      if (root._bokeh_is_loading > 0) {
        console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS is being loaded, scheduling callback at", now());
        return null;
      }
      if (js_urls == null || js_urls.length === 0) {
        run_callbacks();
        return null;
      }
      console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS not loaded, scheduling load and callback at", now());
      root._bokeh_is_loading = js_urls.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < js_urls.length; i++) {
        var url = js_urls[i];
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = url;
        s.async = false;
        s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
          root._bokeh_is_loading--;
          if (root._bokeh_is_loading === 0) {
            console.log("Bokeh: all BokehJS libraries loaded");
            run_callbacks()
          }
        };
        s.onerror = function() {
          console.warn("failed to load library " + url);
        };
        console.log("Bokeh: injecting script tag for BokehJS library: ", url);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
      }
    };var element = document.getElementById("0dd69ef6-4d30-48f5-a95a-1201437920de");
    if (element == null) {
      console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: autoload.js configured with elementid '0dd69ef6-4d30-48f5-a95a-1201437920de' but no matching script tag was found. ")
      return false;
    }

    var js_urls = [];

    var inline_js = [
      function(Bokeh) {
        (function() {
          var fn = function() {
            var docs_json = {"c7d02456-4a61-46d2-8431-34face1e6c67":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["ORDTYP","counts"],"data":{"ORDTYP":["CC","CD","CZ","DB","DR","ED","EI","IC","ID","IP","MC","MF","MI","MK","MP","MS","MX","PC","PM","PT","SD","TI","TX","ZLR"],"counts":[60,3,2,17,1,13,2,28,21,1,3,6,1,2,2,35,10,20,12,2,525,7,225,1]}},"id":"46c2f30a-31d4-4c3f-ade2-4de96e13a4db","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"16eb22e8-c448-49d7-ab20-a02f2ebb3e5c","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"218dbf74-8190-491c-b2dc-d13097c1f9e4","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"03f67199-1622-4784-b9a2-b36b4a47477b","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"d48948b1-297b-4915-bf84-916a417b01ee","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"722ae387-76c5-48cb-a387-7090de91b014","type":"ResetTool"}]},"id":"8ce67c3d-e8dc-41a2-86a8-76685fb90fe9","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"end":525,"start":0},"id":"16f5dfe6-08a6-4ad8-a190-bdf67979b26c","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"bfe7ff64-0995-43a7-8944-6d491bf93b14","type":"CategoricalTicker"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"factors":["CC","CD","CZ","DB","DR","ED","EI","IC","ID","IP","MC","MF","MI","MK","MP","MS","MX","PC","PM","PT","SD","TI","TX","ZLR"]},"id":"36f2f454-71a9-4511-a446-2c56a015ecd0","type":"FactorRange"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Count of Orders","formatter":{"id":"7303c9ca-b3e1-40be-bd44-1ef7f06d8a2d","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"95b801e5-1f32-4ff1-be0c-e64ddcb14fa3","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"bd1e5045-1d72-4e92-8914-13be1ee0d04f","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"95b801e5-1f32-4ff1-be0c-e64ddcb14fa3","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"grid_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"bfe7ff64-0995-43a7-8944-6d491bf93b14","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"0dee56d3-b965-4d15-bf6d-93cd1ea2a20d","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"2a376fc3-0bcc-47df-a0e8-2389040d3254","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":"","text_color":{"value":"black"},"text_font_size":{"value":"12pt"}},"id":"04310042-3ae0-4955-bd48-3d9c8e2d9be2","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{},"id":"722ae387-76c5-48cb-a387-7090de91b014","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"grid_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"95b801e5-1f32-4ff1-be0c-e64ddcb14fa3","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"a281b265-486f-42a3-829a-c71bfd6830d0","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Order Type","formatter":{"id":"259e4d35-20fb-4eb4-9fbd-6068fef93c0d","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"bfe7ff64-0995-43a7-8944-6d491bf93b14","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"9f673b5b-85bf-40d1-96f3-b27737ecc242","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"218dbf74-8190-491c-b2dc-d13097c1f9e4","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"259e4d35-20fb-4eb4-9fbd-6068fef93c0d","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"16eb22e8-c448-49d7-ab20-a02f2ebb3e5c","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"721998c2-dee0-4e47-9a6d-ecef76d53889","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"03f67199-1622-4784-b9a2-b36b4a47477b","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"2a376fc3-0bcc-47df-a0e8-2389040d3254","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"d48948b1-297b-4915-bf84-916a417b01ee","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"46c2f30a-31d4-4c3f-ade2-4de96e13a4db","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"3ab94627-160a-4913-95e6-c25fa17a1d51","type":"VBar"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"f72f6dc1-7c71-4f5e-80f9-fbd1351268b3","type":"VBar"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"9df174a0-4967-47fd-82f3-3d054eee1a12","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"897248ec-4fbd-404c-b3b3-09900b6e3560","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#30a2da"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#000000"},"top":{"field":"counts"},"width":{"value":0.8},"x":{"field":"ORDTYP"}},"id":"f72f6dc1-7c71-4f5e-80f9-fbd1351268b3","type":"VBar"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"#30a2da"},"line_color":{"value":"#000000"},"top":{"field":"counts"},"width":{"value":0.8},"x":{"field":"ORDTYP"}},"id":"3ab94627-160a-4913-95e6-c25fa17a1d51","type":"VBar"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"46c2f30a-31d4-4c3f-ade2-4de96e13a4db","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"9df174a0-4967-47fd-82f3-3d054eee1a12","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"eb1872c1-4fa5-47b0-b5c7-43dfe9b890e3","type":"CategoricalScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"7303c9ca-b3e1-40be-bd44-1ef7f06d8a2d","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"background_fill_color":{"value":"white"},"below":[{"id":"9f673b5b-85bf-40d1-96f3-b27737ecc242","type":"CategoricalAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"bd1e5045-1d72-4e92-8914-13be1ee0d04f","type":"LinearAxis"}],"min_border_bottom":10,"min_border_left":10,"min_border_right":10,"min_border_top":10,"plot_height":300,"plot_width":300,"renderers":[{"id":"9f673b5b-85bf-40d1-96f3-b27737ecc242","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"id":"0dee56d3-b965-4d15-bf6d-93cd1ea2a20d","type":"Grid"},{"id":"bd1e5045-1d72-4e92-8914-13be1ee0d04f","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"a281b265-486f-42a3-829a-c71bfd6830d0","type":"Grid"},{"id":"2a376fc3-0bcc-47df-a0e8-2389040d3254","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"897248ec-4fbd-404c-b3b3-09900b6e3560","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"04310042-3ae0-4955-bd48-3d9c8e2d9be2","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"8ce67c3d-e8dc-41a2-86a8-76685fb90fe9","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"36f2f454-71a9-4511-a446-2c56a015ecd0","type":"FactorRange"},"x_scale":{"id":"eb1872c1-4fa5-47b0-b5c7-43dfe9b890e3","type":"CategoricalScale"},"y_range":{"id":"16f5dfe6-08a6-4ad8-a190-bdf67979b26c","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"721998c2-dee0-4e47-9a6d-ecef76d53889","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}],"root_ids":["c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.12.7"}};
            var render_items = [{"docid":"c7d02456-4a61-46d2-8431-34face1e6c67","elementid":"0dd69ef6-4d30-48f5-a95a-1201437920de","modelid":"c84e964a-0b0b-4d95-aa2c-3657b7811bd0"}];

            Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
          };
          if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
          else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
        })();
      },
      function(Bokeh) {
      }
    ];

    function run_inline_js() {

      if ((root.Bokeh !== undefined) || (force === true)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inline_js.length; i++) {
          inline_js[i].call(root, root.Bokeh);
        }if (force === true) {
          display_loaded();
        }} else if (Date.now() < root._bokeh_timeout) {
        setTimeout(run_inline_js, 100);
      } else if (!root._bokeh_failed_load) {
        console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS failed to load within specified timeout.");
        root._bokeh_failed_load = true;
      } else if (force !== true) {
        var cell = $(document.getElementById("0dd69ef6-4d30-48f5-a95a-1201437920de")).parents('.cell').data().cell;
        cell.output_area.append_execute_result(NB_LOAD_WARNING)
      }

    }

    if (root._bokeh_is_loading === 0) {
      console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS loaded, going straight to plotting");
      run_inline_js();
    } else {
      load_libs(js_urls, function() {
        console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS plotting callback run at", now());
        run_inline_js();
      });
    }
  }(window));
</script></div>
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the JS and CSS that's required to render this output. You can either manually include BokehJS as a script tag, e.g. for bokeh 0.12.9 you'd add this:

```
<link
href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.min.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.9.min.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.6.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can also use the `renderer.static_html` method to export a div which includes all the required JS and CSS, e.g.:

```
hmap = hv.HoloMap({i: hv.Curve(np.random.rand(10)*i) for i in range(1,5)})
html = hv.renderer('bokeh').static_html(hmap)
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

The `static_html` method also accepts a template to embed the JS, CSS and HTML separately:

```
<html>
  <head>
    {css}
    {js}
  </head>
  <body>
    {html}
  </body>
</html>
```

In future releases we will also have a `components` method letting you get the JS, CSS and HTML components separately.

Comment: @phiippjfr Would this Django method of integrating Holoviews work in a Flask environment as well?